# How to stop prettier to keep adding new lines automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, configuration, prettier

I have my formatter installed, which is prettier, and I have enabled the format on save but I come across this problem which is sometimes it adds unnecessary new lines every time I save them, example in an array, like this:

```
const days = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
]
const months = [
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dec',
]
```

Whereas before I saved, it just (and should be) look like this:

```
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

I was wondering what configuration should I make to prevent this change while still keeping the 'format on save' enabled.

Answer (score 2):

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

[image]

Try this, seems to align with what you are looking for. Posted the link to show how `//prettier-ignore` can prevent this from happening on save.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Print Width in Extension Settings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHyif.png

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the biggest problems with prettier and why we have stopped using it on most projects.

There is apparently no way to turn it off because *"prettier is opinionated"*.  Unfortunately, some of the choices made by the creators hurt readability more than they help. (As you have found out.) It would be fine if you could customize it per project but certain formatting rules cannot be controlled.

Try using something like *[js-beautify](https://beautifier.io/)* which is less opinionated and does not attempt to format every aspect of your code.